# I can't verify the role in twig by using is_granted

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-1.4

When I use the function

```
{%if is_granted(CLINET_ROLE) %}
```

By the way whene I check the base I find in colone role this

```
a:1:{i:0;s:11:"CLIENT_ROLE";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, **CLINET_ROLE** instead of **CLIENT_ROLE**

Answer (score 0):

There is typo error. Correct spelling of client in twig file.